# What is the actual behavior of the mov instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, instruction-set

Suppose you have `mov rax, [rsi]` from debugging.
So, how is this instruction actually executed?

Can the address pointed to by the `rsi` register be the L1 cache in the best case?
Or, when the address pointed to by `rsi` is translated, read data from disk or network rather than from main memory?

So what is the worst case if we consider the following conditions when executing the above instruction?

[Latency Comparison Numbers](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832)
L1 cache reference
Branch mispredict
L2 cache reference
Mutex lock/unlock
Main memory reference
Compress 1K bytes with Zippy
Send 1K bytes over 1 Gbps network
Read 4K randomly from SSD*
Read 1 MB sequentially from memory
Round trip within same datacenter
Read 1 MB sequentially from SSD*
Disk seek
Read 1 MB sequentially from disk
Send packet CA->Netherlands->CA

Comment: Yes, a load can hit in the L1. A load can directly read from a storage device only if the device has a proper interface for that (NVRAM is like that, ordinary SSD/HDD are not unless you consider reading from the MMIO data register as a read operation). A load cannot read from the network or another host in general, the closest I can think of is RDMA (cfr: InfiniBand) but that's more than a single load. The rest of the question doesn't make any sense to me. I wouldn't waste any time on that data, measuring load latency in ns makes no sense.

Comment: A load from a memory-mapped file can page-fault, making the kernel run some FS and driver code to get the data from disk or over the network.  But all that work is happening in the page fault handler; the CPU isn't still running the load. It ended with a #PF exception.  And will be retried after the page is present and the kernel returns to user-space with RIP pointing at it.

Comment: The best case for a `mov` from memory is normally an L1d hit, 2 or 3 per clock throughput with about 5 cycle latency.  But on a few CPUs the best case is even better, reloading a recent store with zero latency store-forwarding, in the special case where the CPU can match the address. e.g. Zen 2 has it (but not Zen 3), and Ice Lake.  https://www.agner.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=41